# For primes $p≡3\pmod 4$, prove that $[(p−1)/2]!≡±1\pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory

I know to use Wilson's Theorem and that each element in the second half is congruent to the negative of the first half, but I'm not sure how to construct a proof for it.

Comment: I edited your title because it is extremely likely you did not really mean $P-12$.

Comment: For any p in the form 4k+3, ((p-1)/2)! is congruent to -1 mod p or 1 mod p

Comment: @Amanda did you mean $(p-12)!$ or $((p-1)/2)!$?

Comment: ((p-1)/2)! Sorry!

Comment: A hint: write $p = 4k + 3$ and prove that $((2k + 1)!)^2 = + 1$

Comment: @JonahSinick Why do I want to square (2k+1)!

Comment: Well, somebody already answered, but the point is that the combination of the two facts that you mentioned gives that the square of (2k+1)! Is 1, and then you can conclude that the square root is plus or minus 1, then use that 2k+1 is (p-1)/2

Answer (score 3):

$p-r\equiv -r\pmod p\implies r\equiv-(p-r)$

For uniqueness, $r\le p-r$ or $2r\le p\implies r\le\frac p 2$

So, $1\le r\le \frac{p-1}2$ as $p$ is odd

Putting $r=1,2,3,\cdots,\frac{p-3}2,\frac{p-1}2$ we get,

$1\equiv-(p-1)$

$2\equiv-(p-2)$

...

$\frac{p-3}2\equiv-(p-\frac{p-3}2)=\frac{p+3}2$

$\frac{p-1}2\equiv-(p-\frac{p-1}2)=\frac{p+1}2$

So, there are $\frac{p-1}2$ pairs so,

$(p-1)!=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\left((\frac{p-1}2)!\right)^2$

Using Wilson's theorem, $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\left((\frac{p-1}2)!\right)^2\equiv-1\pmod p$

If $p\equiv3\pmod 4,p=4t+3$ for some integer $t$,

So, $\frac{p-1}2=2t+1$ which is odd, so $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}=-1$

$\implies \left((\frac{p-1}2)!\right)^2\equiv1\pmod p$

$\implies \left(\frac{p-1}2 \right)!\equiv\pm1\pmod p$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\binom{p-1}{k}\equiv (-1)^k \pmod{p}$ (apply the fact that $p\mid \binom{p}{k}$ for $1\leq k\leq p-1$, and the recursive formula for obtaining binomial coefficients).

Now we have $\frac{(p-1)!}{(\frac{p-1}{2})!(\frac{p-1}{2})!}\equiv\binom{p-1}{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, and thus $-1\equiv(p-1)!\equiv (-1)((\frac{p-1}{2})!)^2 \pmod{p}$. So $(\frac{p-1}{2})!$ is a square root of 1 modulo $p$, hence is $\pm1$.