# If $p$ is an odd prime of the form $p=3\pmod{4}$, then prove that $((p-1)/2)!=1$ or $-1\pmod{p}$.

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is an odd prime of the form $p=3 \pmod{4}$, then prove that

$$
\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!=1 \text{ or } -1\pmod{p}.
$$

Comment: Do you know Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Yes. It seems that have to apply it. But can not relateit with(p-1)!=-1(mod p)

Comment: Write $$(p-1)! = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\cdot \prod_{k= (p+1)/2}^{p-1} k.$$ Look how the second product relates to $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Fischer. I have got it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222372/for-primes-p3-pmod-4-prove-that-p1-21-pmod-p/222427#222427